# C#: DateTime convert

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am recieving a date in the format:

```
18/04/2011 4:57:20 PM
```

The `DateTime.Parse()` method does not access it.

Is there a way to get it to convert `18/04/2011 4:57:20 PM` to return a `Date` object `April 18, 2011`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't look like a standard format. The date is en-GB, the time en-US. Because of this, I would recommend you use DateTime.ParseExact and pass the format:

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact("18/04/2011 4:57:20 PM", 
                                      "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, to change the format of a date, you need a `DateTime` value. You can not format a string date. Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to extract your date value from a formated date string:

```
DateTime dateValue = 
   DateTime.ParseExact(stringDateValue, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can use [DateTime.ToString(format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to extract a formated string value:

```
resultStringDateValue = dateValue.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ParseExact or better TryParseExact (that not generate exception when fail), with this two method you can pass the format provider description as parameter :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Convert.ToDateTime(String)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xhz1w05e(v=VS.90).aspx

You'll have to see if Convert.ToDateTime accept the format you want to input it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

your date format is mm/dd/yyyy there is no month of 18

try this

```
DateTime.Parse("04/18/2011 4:57:20PM").ToShortDateString();
```